# Separability of a dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and assume that $(B_X, \text{weak})$ is metrizable.

WLOG, we may assume that

$$U_n = \{ x \in B_X : | f(x) | < 1, \, f \in F_n \},$$ where $F_n$ is a finite subset of $X^*$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, form a countable base of nbhs of $0$ in $(B_X, \text{weak})$.

To see that $X^*$ is separable, it is enough to show that $\overline{\text{span}} (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n ) = X^*$

Under this situation, pick $x^{**} \in X^{**}$ that vanishes on $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$.

According to the textbook (Fabian), there exists a net $\{x_{\alpha}\}$ in $B_X$ that $\text{weak}^*$-converges to $x^{**}$.

I think the Goldstine theorem is used here.

But then, how can we know that such $x^{**}$ lies in $B_{X^{**}}$ (to apply the Goldstine theorem)?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Consider $x^{**}/\|x^{**}\|$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin WOW. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @John Griffin said, by considering $x^{**}/\|x^{**}\|$, we can choose a net $\{x_{\alpha}\}$ in $B_{X}$ that $\text{weak}^*$-converges to $x^{**}/\|x^{**}\|$.

Here, we assumed that $x^{**} \neq 0$.

From the fact that for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $\alpha_0$ such that  $$ |\,f(x_{\alpha})| = \left| \, f\left( \frac{x^{**}}{\|x^{**}\|} - x_{\alpha}\right) \right| < 1 $$
for all $f \in F_n$ whenever $\alpha \geq \alpha_0$, we can conclude that
$x_{\alpha} \in U_n$ for $\alpha \geq \alpha_0$.

Hence $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow 0$ in weak-sense; thus $x^{**}/\|x^{**}\| = 0$, a contradiction!

Thus, $x^{**} = 0$.

It follows that $\left(\text{span}\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n\right)\right)^{\perp} = \{0\}$, therefore $\overline{\text{span}}\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n\right) = X^{*}.$

The proof is done.